# How to remove a Windows share when the folder does not exist anymore?

Tags: network-share, share

I have some shared folders in the list in 'Computer Management' that point to folders that dont exist anymore. But Windows wont let me remove them, "The system cannot find the path specified", maybe a net * command through the console could solve it?

Comment: Does it show up when you use `net use` in a command prompt?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Shares are listed in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares` registry key, you can delete the entries there, after a backup of the key ([source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125996/en-us))

Answer (score 1):

If you know the source folder you may just recreate it and use the GUI functions for Sharing in Windows explorer

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I had to put a USB stick in and reassign the drive letter, but then I could just "unshare" it. I also ran `fsmgmt.msc` from the Run window and found it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remember that you've NOT used a removable drive or a CD to share folders off those drives. 
If you in fact did share folders off those drives, you can mount that drive (USB-in the HDD or insert the CD with those previously shared folders) and remove the shares using normal Windows Share menu (Advanced Share) options.

If you no longer have that removable drive - then delete the keys in the registry.